# Probability dice game, multiple turns

Tags: probability, recurrence-relations, dice

> Alice and Bob are playing dices, Alice begins.
>
> If the current player gets a 6, he wins. If he gets 4 ou 5, he plays again. Else, the other player plays.
>
> Let $p_n$ (resp. $q_n$) be the probability of the event $P_n$: "Alice (resp. Bob) plays at the turn $n$", and $r_n$ be the probability of the event "The game is over at the turn $n$".
>
> 1. Determine a recurrence relation between $p_{n+1}$, $p_n$ and $r_n$.

I think I am ok for this question:
$$p_{n+1} = \frac 2 6 p_n + \frac 1 2 q_n = \frac 13 p_n + \frac 1 2 (1 - r_n-p_n) = \frac 1 2 \overline{r_n}-\frac 1 6 p_n,$$
and
$$q_{n+1} = \dots = \frac 1 3 \overline{r_n} +  \frac 1 6 p_n.$$
we easily have $\overline{r_n}= {\left(\dfrac{5}{6}\right)}^{n-1}$, which can be insert
in the above formulae.

> 2. Deduce the probability that Alice wins in $n$ turns, and then in less than $n$ turn.

I'm stuck here : we want to compute : $P(P_n \cap R_{n+1} ) = P(R_{n+1} | P_n ) P(P_n) = \frac 1 6 p_n$... But I don't see how to compute $p_n$.

Comment: I'm not sure your formula for $\overline{r_n}$ is correct. For one, $\overline{r_1}$ is $\frac{5}{6}$.

Comment: Nope, $\overline{r_1}=1$. $r_n$ is not the probability that the game stops at turn $n$, but the probability that game is already finished at turn $n$.

Comment: Off-by-one then... $\overline{r_2} = \frac56$.

Comment: Okay, my bad. $r_n = (\frac 5 6) ^n$.

Answer (score 1):

I construct a probability tree for Alice:

```
1/2  1/2  1/2 ... Bob plays
 ^    ^    ^
 |    |    |
-+1/3-+1/3-+1/3-> ... Alice continues
 |    |    |
 v    v    v
1/6  1/6  1/6 ... Alice wins
```

The probability that Alice (or Bob, by symmetry) wins on this turn is $\frac 16\left(1+\frac 13+\frac 19+\frac 1{27}+\dots\right)=\frac 14$. Now consider the whole game tree:

```
 A    B    A    B ... wins
1/4  1/4  1/4  1/4
 ^    ^    ^    ^
 |    |    |    |
-+3/4-+3/4-+3/4-+3/4-> game continues
 1         2         < turn count
```

$p_1=1$, $p_{n+1}=\frac 9{16}p_n$ and $r_n=\frac 7{16}p_n$. The probability that Alice wins in exactly *n* turns is $\frac 14\left(\frac 9{16}\right)^{n-1}$, and in less than *n* turns
$$\frac 14\sum_{k=0}^{n-2} \left(\frac 9{16}\right)^k=\frac 4{63}\left(9-16\left(\frac 9{16}\right)^n\right).$$